# SQL BULK INSERT FROM errors

Tags: sql, bulkinsert

I'm attempting to insert a CSV file into an Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio database like this:

```
    BULK INSERT [dbo].[STUDY]
        FROM 'C:\Documents and Settings\Adam\My Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Projects\StudyTable.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        MAXERRORS = 0,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

But I am getting errors:

```
    Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
    Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 9 (STATUS).

    Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
    The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

    Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
    Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide the contents of `StudyTable.csv`, to protect the privacy of the company we're working for.

**EDIT** I can vouch for the validity of the `csv` file though. It was exported from OpenOffice's version of Excel, and I went through and made sure it was valid.

**EDIT2**
Here's a dummy version of the CSV file:

```
    1234,,,1234,1234,,"asdf","asdf","Z","asd",7/1/2010 12:23,8/5/2010 13:36,9/4/2010 13:36,"(asdf,1661,#1234,F,T)","F",,,"F",,"68866",1234,1234,1234,"F"
```

Here's a create script for the `STUDY` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDY]
(
    [STUDY_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PARENT_ID] INT,
    [GROUP_ID] INT,
    [WORKFLOW_NODE_ID] INT,
    [STUDY_TEMPLATE_ID] INT,
    [INSPECTION_PLAN_ID] INT,
    [NAME] VARCHAR(255),
    [DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(4000),
    [STATUS] VARCHAR,
    [OLD_STATUS] VARCHAR,
    [CREATED_ON] DATE,
    [COMPLETED_ON] DATE,
    [AUTHORIZED_ON] DATE,
    [EVENTS] VARCHAR,
    [NEEDS_REVIEW] CHAR,
    [HAS_NOTES] CHAR,
    [HAS_AUDITS] CHAR,
    [STUDY_PART] CHAR,
    [STUDY_TYPE] VARCHAR,
    [EXTERNAL_REFERENCE] VARCHAR,
    [CREATED_BY] INT,
    [COMPLETED_BY] INT,
    [AUTHORISED_BY] INT,
    [ARCHIVED_CHILD_COMPLETE] CHAR
)
```

Comment: More info is going to be needed to help with this.  Your error is occurring on row 1, so maybe create and post a single dummy row?  Also, what does the STUDY table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the data in your `STATUS` column in the .csv file is longer than the definition for the field in your SQL Table.

Check the definition on that field and make sure the data you have in the .csv will fit (both length and type).

Comment: It was `CHAR(1)`, and I changed it to `VARCHAR`; still no luck.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins - How long is the status field in the .csv file?  You still need to specify a max length for varchar fields.

Comment: Its a maximum of one character

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins - you need to account for the double quotes on your strings: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1602

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins - I think it's inserting the doublequotes as part of the string, which is why....check the table to see.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is likely because a column is too big to fit the database. First thought is does the CSV file contain column headers?

The second error is very generic.

Do any of your fields contain a comma as part of their data - for example *37, High Street* which isn't encased in quotes? I've come unstuck lots of times in the past because of "issues" in the data (the data is valid, just not quite what's expected). If your CSV file is a few thousand rows or more - what happens if you try importing just the first hundred (or ten) rows?

Comment: No headers. Its only one row.